# TSQL Group/Split Together in Multiple of X based on Variable Column Values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

I want the following dataset to be grouped or split based on 'Drv_uniqId'.

The relationship between `Drv_uniqId` and `Trk_uniqId` can be one-2-one or one-2-many (upto a maximum of 10). That is one `Drv_uniqId` can be assigned to upto 10 `Trk_uniqId`

The relationship between `Trk_uniqId` and `Drv_uniqId` can be one-2-one or one-2-many (upto a maximum of 4). That is one `Trk_uniqId` can be assigned to upto 4 `Drv_uniqId`

The data can consist of all unique `Drv_uniqId` and `Trk_uniqId` combinations. I am to show this data in a report and I can't show one row on each page. The Group/split will be used in SSRS to split the final report into multiple pages.

**Rules**

Each `Drv_uniqId` must within the same Group. Can not be split over multiple groups.

Each group = Minimum 5 rows and maximum 10 rows

DDL

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1,530,'4392 T_01'),
(2,540,'4209 H_01'),
(3,540,'4551 T_01'),
(4,543,'4407 T_01'),
(5,543,'4691 T_01'),
(6,546,'4691 T_01'),
(7,546,'4579 T_01'),
(8,757,'4688 T_01'),
(9,757,'4689 T_01'),
(10,757,'4691 T_01'),
(11,757,'4407 T_01'),
(12,855,'4410 T_01'),
(13,1249,'4583 A_01'),
(14,1324,'4689 T_01'),
(15,1324,'4690 T_01'),
(16,1411,'4689 T_01'),
(17,1411,'4690 T_01'),
(18,1411,'4478 A_01'),
(19,1411,'4411 T_01'),
(20,1411,'4692 T_01'),
(21,1411,'4406 T_01'),
(22,2115,'4410 T_01'),
(23,2115,'4414 T_01'),
(24,2115,'4422 T_01'),
(25,2325,'3422 T_01') ,
(26,2325,'4522 T_01') ,
(27,2330,'4462 T_01')   ) tbl (Id,Drv_uniqId,Trk_uniqId)
```

I've removed the sample expected output as it doesn't matter what group any `Drv_uniqId` goes in just as long as they don't exist in multiple groups - any solution doesn't have to match this output just the rules.
Minimum 5 and maximum 10

Comment: Provide please expected output

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the logic...

Comment: @Shnugo I want to be able to group or split the data based on `Drv_uniqId` .  The `Drv_uniqId` can not exist in multiple groups

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze, this I can find within the question already. But please explain in normal language why e.g. row 8 is in group 2 or why Group 3 consists of 1411 only, but Group 4 has several `Drv_uniqId` values. This might be clear for you, but I cannot see any rule...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I also can't get the logic. Why records 1-7 are in the same group, and why 8-15 are in a different one?

Comment: @Shnugo @zoharPeled Oh, I understand now, It doesn't matter what group any `Drv_uniqId` goes in just as long as they don't exist in multiple groups

Comment: Do you have other conditions like minimum or maximum number of groups?

Comment: @uzi No other conditions

Comment: Then why do not you make group for each `Drv_uniqId`?

Answer (score 0):

If the only rule is that you can't have the same `Drv_uniqId` value in more than one group, you can use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql) ordered by `Drv_uniqId` to get the groups:

```
SELECT  *, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Drv_uniqId) rnk
FROM (VALUES
(1,530,'4392 T_01'),
(2,540,'4209 H_01'),
(3,540,'4551 T_01'),
(4,543,'4407 T_01'),
(5,543,'4691 T_01'),
(6,546,'4691 T_01'),
(7,546,'4579 T_01'),
(8,757,'4688 T_01'),
(9,757,'4689 T_01'),
(10,757,'4691 T_01'),
(11,757,'4407 T_01'),
(12,855,'4410 T_01'),
(13,1249,'4583 A_01'),
(14,1324,'4689 T_01'),
(15,1324,'4690 T_01'),
(16,1411,'4689 T_01'),
(17,1411,'4690 T_01'),
(18,1411,'4478 A_01'),
(19,1411,'4411 T_01'),
(20,1411,'4692 T_01'),
(21,1411,'4406 T_01'),
(22,2115,'4410 T_01'),
(23,2115,'4414 T_01'),
(24,2115,'4422 T_01'),
(25,2325,'3422 T_01') ,
(26,2325,'4522 T_01') ,
(27,2330,'4462 T_01')   ) tbl (Id,Drv_uniqId,Trk_uniqId) 
ORDER BY Id
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/RFMJ48974)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to clarify my question.  It's not a requirement to have just one `Drv_uniqId` in each group which `DENSE_RANK` shows

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze but there is no rule against it, correct? It's easier to write (and for sql server to execute) it like this then to start calculating groups that span over more than one `Drv_uniqId`...

Answer (score 0):

My attempt involves a WHILE LOOP and calculates Running Total 
If anyone can provide a better alternative then that would be appreciated

```
DECLARE @tbl_table TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), PartitionId INT, Total_Drv_uniqId INT NULL, Drv_uniqId INT, Trk_uniqId NVARCHAR(50), GrpSplit INT NULL );

;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT
          tbl.Id
        , tbl.Drv_uniqId
        , tbl.Trk_uniqId
    FROM (VALUES
        (1,530,'4392 T_01'),
        (2,540,'4209 H_01'),
        (3,540,'4551 T_01'),
        (4,543,'4407 T_01'),
        (5,543,'4691 T_01'),
        (6,546,'4691 T_01'),
        (7,546,'4579 T_01'),
        (8,757,'4688 T_01'),
        (9,757,'4689 T_01'),
        (10,757,'4691 T_01'),
        (11,757,'4407 T_01'),
        (12,855,'4410 T_01'),
        (13,1249,'4583 A_01'),
        (14,1324,'4689 T_01'),
        (15,1324,'4690 T_01'),
        (16,1411,'4689 T_01'),
        (17,1411,'4690 T_01'),
        (18,1411,'4478 A_01'),
        (19,1411,'4411 T_01'),
        (20,1411,'4692 T_01'),
        (21,1411,'4406 T_01'),
        (22,2115,'4410 T_01'),
        (23,2115,'4414 T_01'),
        (24,2115,'4422 T_01'),
        (25,2325,'3422 T_01') ,
        (26,2325,'4522 T_01') ,
        (27,2330,'4462 T_01')   ) tbl (Id,Drv_uniqId,Trk_uniqId) 
)
INSERT INTO @tbl_table
(PartitionId, Total_Drv_uniqId, Drv_uniqId, Trk_uniqId)
SELECT 
      RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY X.Drv_uniqId ORDER BY X.Drv_uniqId)
    , COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY X.Drv_uniqId)
    , X.Drv_uniqId
    , X.Trk_uniqId
FROM cteX X;
--GROUP BY X.Drv_uniqId

--Set Total_Drv_uniqId to 0 for duplicate rows so that Running total below is accurate
UPDATE @tbl_table SET Total_Drv_uniqId = 0 WHERE PartitionId > 1;

DECLARE @GrpSplit INT = 1, @maxLoop INT =1, @Rows INT;
SET @maxLoop = (SELECT MAX(V.Id) FROM @tbl_table V);

--Loop though to set GrpSplit using Running Total of [Total_Drv_uniqId]
WHILE @GrpSplit <= @maxLoop 
BEGIN

    UPDATE N
    SET N.GrpSplit = @GrpSplit
    FROM @tbl_table N
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID
            , T1.Total_Drv_uniqId
            ,RunningTotal = (   SELECT SUM(T2.Total_Drv_uniqId)
                                FROM @tbl_table T2
                                WHERE T2.ID <= T1.ID
                            ) 
        FROM @tbl_table T1
        WHERE ( SELECT SUM(T2.Total_Drv_uniqId)
                FROM @tbl_table T2
                WHERE T2.ID <= T1.ID
                AND T2.GrpSplit IS NULL
             ) < 10
        AND T1.GrpSplit IS NULL
    ) X ON X.Id = N.Id;
    SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT ;

    IF @Rows < 1 BREAK ; --Break when no more rows to update 

    SET @GrpSplit += 1 ;

END;

SELECT T.Id, T.Drv_uniqId
     , T.Trk_uniqId
     , T.GrpSplit FROM @tbl_table T;
```

Output

```
Id  Drv_uniqId  Trk_uniqId  GrpSplit
1   530         4392 T_01   1
2   540         4551 T_01   1
3   540         4209 H_01   1
4   543         4691 T_01   1
5   543         4407 T_01   1
6   546         4691 T_01   1
7   546         4579 T_01   1
8   757         4689 T_01   2
9   757         4691 T_01   2
10  757         4407 T_01   2
11  757         4688 T_01   2
12  855         4410 T_01   2
13  1249        4583 A_01   2
14  1324        4689 T_01   2
15  1324        4690 T_01   2
16  1411        4690 T_01   3
17  1411        4478 A_01   3
18  1411        4411 T_01   3
19  1411        4692 T_01   3
20  1411        4406 T_01   3
21  1411        4689 T_01   3
22  2115        4410 T_01   3
23  2115        4414 T_01   3
24  2115        4422 T_01   3
25  2325        4522 T_01   4
26  2325        3422 T_01   4
27  2330        4462 T_01   4
```